# Woman traveling on foot with a falcon companion in a feudal culture

Tags: story-identification, novel, young-adult

I believe it is stand alone, though I am not entirely confident. all I remember is the cover and one specific scene:

The cover consisted of green, brown, and gold colors depicting a forest with a women standing in the center emerging from foliage and looking up into the sky. her hair is bound with ribbon in a braid like style down her back and a falcon is flying above her.

I also remember that she is traveling for most of the book and is very personally bonded with her falcon.

There is a scene where she is imprisoned and sick and she is able to transfer her soul into the falcon and search for help from a guy friend of hers.

The book is set in the times of kings and queens when there were huge forests and the only means of transportation if you weren't ridiculously rich was by foot.

I cant remember if she was of nobility but there were plenty of times in the book where people were surprised of her ability to take care of herself as well as hunt and use a bow and arrow

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When did you read this?  Were there any overt magical elements other than the soul connection with her companion?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is [*Hawksmaid: The Untold Story of Robin Hood and Maid Marian*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/6558152-hawksmaid) by Kathryn Lasky.

> *As the daughter of Nottingham's most famous falconer, she finds a new destiny in the hawks her father keeps. She begins to understand their thoughts and even speak their language. The beautiful merlin Marigold becomes Matty's closest winged companion and her fiercest ally.*

[image]